# How to get id in response of Button in the Grid of yii

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii

I am using buttons in grid of Yii

```
                                 'change_password' => array(                                
                                            'label' => '<i class="icon-lock"></i>',                                
                                            'options' => array('title' => 'Change password'),                             
                                            'url' => 'Yii::app()->createUrl("user/editPassword",array("id"=>$data->id))', 
                                            'click' => 'function(){  $.get( $(this).attr("href"), function( data ) { 
                                                var response = JSON.parse(data); 
                                                var name = response.user;
                                                if(name  ==""){
                                                    name= "User";
                                                }
                                                $(".passwordheading").text(name);
var id =$(this).parents("tr").attr("id"); alert(id);
                                                $("#password-form #User_id").val(id); 
                                                $("#passwordDiv").show();  

                                            }); return false; }',
                                ),
```

Here i am passing id to controller.  In response i am getting only name. 
How can i get id in response from here.
I tried `var id = $data->id` and `var id =$(this).parents("tr").attr("id");`
But didn't get value.

Please help.

Comment: Add your controller action in your post.

Comment: I dont want to fetch it from controller.

Answer (score 0):

Event `click` has no access `$data` property. You have to ways:

1. Create first column ID and hide it if you needn't. Then get id value:

   `var id = $(this).parent().parent().children(':first-child').text();`
2. Add `rowHtmlOptionsExpression` param:

   `'rowHtmlOptionsExpression' => 'array("data-id" => $data->id)'`

Then get `data-id`:

```
var id = $(this).parent().parent().data('id')
```

Comment: I given second option. But still didnt get  id in response. Row came as  <tr data-id="2757" class="odd">

Comment: First of all check `this` context, it must be a button you clicked and not a context of $.get() function or other. Then check parent traversing. You need to get parent tr.